# How to select an option from a select list with React Testing Library

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a normal select list. I need to test handleChoice gets called when I choose an option. How can I do this with React Testing Library?

```
  <select
    onChange={handleChoice}
    data-testid="select"
  >
    <option value="default">Make your choice</option>
    {attributes.map(item => {
      return (
        <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>
          {item.label}
        </option>
      );
    })}
  </select>
```

`getByDisplayValue` with the value of `item.label` doesn't return anything, perhaps this is because it's not visible on the page?

Comment: Have you tried `fireEvent.change(getByTestId("select"), { target: { value: '<item label>' } });`

Comment: It seems to not like getByTestId("select"), I get an error: TypeError: container.querySelectorAll is not a function

Comment: Keep scrolling below for a most idiomatic answer, provided by @helen8287 : https://stackoverflow.com/a/69558645/72351

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Add `data-testid` to the options

```js
  <option data-testid="select-option" key={item.key} value={item.key}>
      {item.label}
  </option>
```

Then, in the test call `fireEvent.change`, get all the options by `getAllByTestId` and check the selected option:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render, fireEvent } from '@testing-library/react';
import App from './App';

test('Simulates selection', () => {
  const { getByTestId, getAllByTestId } = render(<App />);
  //The value should be the key of the option
  fireEvent.change(getByTestId('select'), { target: { value: 2 } })
  let options = getAllByTestId('select-option')
  expect(options[0].selected).toBeFalsy();
  expect(options[1].selected).toBeTruthy();
  expect(options[2].selected).toBeFalsy();
  //...
})
```

For your question, the `getByDisplayValue` works only on displayed values

Comment: `fireEvent.change` doesn't work for me; I used `fireEvent.click` and it worked fine.

Comment: instead of `getByTestId('select')` you can use `getByRole('combobox')`

Comment: NOTE: "value: 2" is not referring to the index of values but chooses the option with the value set to "2". If your values are not a number, make sure to do: 
"value: <your value>" on the fireEvent.

Comment: Thanks, was looking for a way to test for selected

Comment: But the same code not working with Angular Material. is it require any additional workaround?

Comment: I created an updated answer using the suggestions by Tomasz Mularczyk and Logan Cundiff for an easier example

Comment: @incarnate 's comment should be the answer

Answer (score 47):

This solution didn't work for me, what did work, was userEvent.
https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
    import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
    import App from './App';
    
    test('Simulates selection', () => {
      const { getByTestId } = render(<App />);
      // where <value> is the option value without angle brackets!
      userEvent.selectOptions(getByTestId('select'), '<value>');
      expect((getByTestId('<value>') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBeTruthy();
      expect((getByTestId('<another value>') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBeFalsy();
      //...
    })
```

You can also forgo having to add a `data-testid` to the select element if you have a label (which you should!), and simply use `getByLabelText('Select')`

Further still, you can get rid of the additional `data-testid` on each option element, if you use `getByText`.

```js
      <label for="selectId">
            Select
      </label>
      <select
        onChange={handleChoice}
        id="selectId"
      >
        <option value="default">Make your choice</option>
        {attributes.map(item => {
          return (
            <option key={item.key} value={item.key}>
              {item.label}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
```

Then:

```js
    import React from 'react';
    import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
    import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';
    import App from './App';
    
    test('Simulates selection', () => {
      const { getByLabelText, getByText } = render(<App />);
      // where <value> is the option value without angle brackets!
      userEvent.selectOptions(getByLabelText('<your select label text>'), '<value>');
      expect((getByText('<your selected option text>') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBeTruthy();
      expect((getByText('<another option text>') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBeFalsy();
      //...
    })
```

This seems a more optimal way to do this type of test.

Comment: I'm running `"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.2.1"` and your solution worked for me. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 38):

**In 2021, you can use [userEvent](https://testing-library.com/docs/ecosystem-user-event/) which comes as part of the React Testing Library ecosystem. It allows you to write tests which are closer to real user behaviour. Example

```js
    it('should correctly set default option', () => {
      render(<App />)
      expect(screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'Make a choice'}).selected).toBe(true)
    })


    it('should allow user to change country', () => {
      render(<App />)
      userEvent.selectOptions(
        // Find the select element
        screen.getByRole('combobox'),
        // Find and select the Ireland option
        screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'Ireland'}),
      )
      expect(screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'Ireland'}).selected).toBe(true)
    })
```

Have a look at [this article](https://cathalmacdonnacha.com/how-to-test-a-select-element-with-react-testing-library) for more info on how to test select elements using React Testing Library.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use `getByText` which will save you from adding the `data-testid` attribute

In my case I did

```
import { screen } from '@testing-library/react';

....
<select>
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option selected value="bar">Bar</option>
</select>

....

expect((screen.getByText('Foo') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBeFalsy();
expect((screen.getByText('Bar') as HTMLOptionElement).selected).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 6):

This seems simpler to me:

```
userEvent.selectOptions(screen.getByLabelText('County'), 'Aberdeenshire');
```

Comment: This answer is much simpler and should be accepted

Answer (score 3):

### 1: Install `user-event` V14 and above

npm:

> npm install --save-dev @testing-library/user-event

yarn:

> yarn add --dev @testing-library/user-event

---

### 2: Import and set in up: (it's a default import so make sure you didn't import named one)

```js
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('should change data', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
});
```

---

## 3: Change selected option and test:

```js
import userEvent from '@testing-library/user-event';

test('should change data', async () => {
    const user = userEvent.setup();
    
    // Check if default value in correct:
    expect(screen.getByRole('option', { name: /default option/i }).selected).toBeTruthy();
    
    // Change option: (Make sure to use Async/Await syntax)
    await user.selectOptions(screen.getByRole("combobox"), 'optionToSelect');
    
    // Check the result:
    expect(screen.getByRole('option', { name: /optionToSelect/i }).selected).toBeTruthy();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was checking a number against a string, which failed. I had to convert the number with toString() to make it work.

The HTML:

```html
<select>
<option value="1">Hello</option>
<option value="2">World</option>
</select>
```

And in my test:

```js
await fireEvent.change(select, { target: { value: categories[0].id.toString() } });

expect(options[1].selected).toBeTruthy();
```

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answers here to create a short way to achieve this using `fireEvent`. For this example I'm using a selector with 6 color options.

```
fireEvent.change(screen.getByRole('combobox'), { target: { value: "green" } });
const options = screen.getAllByRole('option');
expect(options).toHaveLength(6); 
expect(options[1].selected).toBeTruthy(); // green is the second option in this case
```

Here, "green" refers to the value of the option, so change this for your own use ie. `value: <your value>`.