# Given 2 combobox, how to select an option from a select list with React Testing Library

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

So i'm following this example
[How to select an option from a select list with React Testing Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57946870/how-to-select-an-option-from-a-select-list-with-react-testing-library)

Now in my case i have 2 dropdown lists,

```
<select data-testid="select state">
  <option>
    CA
  </option>
  <option>
    NY 
  </option>
  <option>
    MA
  </option>
</select>

<select data-testid="select city">
  <option>
    New York
  </option>
  <option>
    San Diego
  </option>
</select>
```

Assuming i only have the 1st dropdown, the test can be like this to choose 'MA'

```
it('should correctly set default option', () => {
  render(<App />)
  expect(screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'CA'}).selected).toBe(true)
})


it('should allow ...', () => {
  render(<App />)
  userEvent.selectOptions(
    // Find the select element
    screen.getByRole('combobox'),
    // Find and select the Ireland option
    screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'MA'}),
  )
  expect(screen.getByRole('option', {name: 'MA'}).selected).toBe(true)
})
```

Q1: if i turn on the 2nd dropdown list, the unit test reports:
Found multiple elements with the role "combobox"
How should i update the test pls ?

Q2: i tried to replace

```
screen.getByRole('combobox')
```

with

```
screen.getByTest('select state')
```

The original sample test will fail, it cannot see the other options other than the 1st default option.

Any suggestions pls ?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, there's a space in the option names 'MA '.
i removed the space and things start working